# Trying to convert unix timestamp to the day but same amount of days is being printed instead. Using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm calling an api that provides the daily forecast for 7 days. I've written code to try and convert the dt unix into days..but im getting the same  times multiple times instead...https://gyazo.com/4f9d207ea2c3350c5fc30fa66d344634

Api json - https://gyazo.com/a03056058730f97ed63a94489da0ec94

problem - >https://gyazo.com/009e8367331c34ceb205e42d0710e142

My code -

```
import Card from './components/Card';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';



function App() {
const [query, updateQuery] = useState()
const [weather, updateWeather] = useState()
const [forecast, updateForecast] = useState()


const search = (evt) => {
  if (evt.key === "Enter"){
    axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${query}&appid=`).then((res) => {
      const currentData = res.data;
      
      updateQuery("")
      updateWeather(currentData)
      
      axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${currentData.coord.lat}&lon=${currentData.coord.lon}&exclude=current,hourly,minutely,alerts&units=metric&appid=`).then((res) => {
        const forecastData = res.data;
 
  updateForecast(forecastData)


  const days = ['Friday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday'];

const fiveForecastDays = forecast.daily.map(({ dt }) => days[new Date(dt).getDay()]);
console.log(fiveForecastDays);
  
  
})

    })
   
  }
}




const queryHandler=(e)=>{
  // console.log(e.target.value)
  updateQuery(e.target.value)
  }
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={queryHandler} value={query} onKeyPress={search} type="text"/>
        
    
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the asynchronous nature of state update, when you do:

```
updateQuery("")
updateWeather(currentData)
```

It doesn't update immediately, so the request in next line is sent with previous state.

To fix this problem, you should fire the request from a side effect that is triggered when this state updates, using `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${currentData.coord.lat}&lon=${currentData.coord.lon}&exclude=current,hourly,minutely,alerts&units=metric&appid=`).then((res) => {
    const forecastData = res.data;
    updateForecast(forecastData)
    // ....
   
}, [currentData]);
```

Your first request should also likely be a side effect of `updateQuery` changing.

Comment: @braindead401 nope, go ahead (typing from phone can't format stuff anymore)

Comment: In case you didnt get it - repost

#1 Are you able to put a useEffect in a function(for my example the search function? #2 Also would you say I should also use a useEffect for my first api call?
#3 I also get undefined when im trying to map through the response..any idea on a solution

Comment: 1. useeffect should be on top level of function component (can't be inside nested functions) 2. Yes. 3. You prob need a `if(!mystate){return}` guard inside it to not send invalid values to api

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it with my example cause theirs alot of scope issues and my search function (if key entered i press then api is fetched) works properly inside a useEffect..Would i be able to put down my code and then maybe have you look at it later?

Comment: Consider creating a codesandbox (its midnight so Ill only be able to see it in like 8hrs